# How can I prevent opens the linked document in the full body of the window. Mozilla Firefox about:config

Tags: javascript, java, php, dom, firefox-developer-tools

Example I've an image where am using target="_top"  onclicking that image tag will loads the target page in the same window. I need to prevent this action and it should load in the new window or new tab. and also i need to execute the solution in Firefox headless binary .

Example url: http://publish.rcc.bps-core.com/creative_preview/rtb/3101/5e/ec/5eec90874448307ca9e49676411afc96.html

All I need is when clicking the image from the above url. it should not load the target url in the same window.  instead it should load in the separate window or tab.

Comment: Thanks for you replay I don't want to fix this thing in code. I need to know the way how to achieve this from **about:config preferences**

Comment: Ah, ok. So you want to prevent sites from breaking out of a frameset? Not sure whether that can be done with 100% reliability even if there *were* such an about:config option.

Comment: Can any one give any suggestions ?